# Setting up a 3 level menu in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I want to add a 3 level dropdown menu to my site.

I think, my html code is right, and i also added the css codes, but the last dropdown menu's are at wrong place.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    
                    <a href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/14/ajandektargy-nyomtatas"data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" title="Ajándéktárgy nyomtatás">Menu 1</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/15/ajandektargy-nyomtatas/bogre-nyomtatas" title="Bögre nyomtatás">Menu 2</a> 
                                                    
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                                                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                                                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                                                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    
                                                    </li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/16/ajandektargy-nyomtatas/polo-nyomtatas" title="Póló nyomtatás">Póló nyomtatás</a> </li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/17/ajandektargy-nyomtatas/baba-ruha-nyomtatas" title="Baba ruha nyomtatás">Baba ruha nyomtatás</a> </li>
                                            </ul>
                    
                    </li>
```

Some css:

```
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu { top: 0; left: 100%; }
.dropdown-submenu a::after {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 1.425em;
}
```

Also, you can take a look at the site [here.](https://teszt.pecelkft.hu/gyik)
Just hover down the Menu 1 menuitem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `dropdown-menu` to be `dropdown-submenu` in the `<ul>` element, as you can see in the code below, hope this works!

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/14/ajandektargy-nyomtatas" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" title="Ajándéktárgy nyomtatás">Menu 1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/15/ajandektargy-nyomtatas/bogre-nyomtatas" title="Bögre nyomtatás">Menu 2</a> 
                            <ul class="dropdown-submenu"> <!-- I changed this to dropdown-submenu -->
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://szakkereskedo.hu/kategoria/137/betonadalekszerek/folyositok" title="Folyósítók">Menu 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/16/ajandektargy-nyomtatas/polo-nyomtatas" title="Póló nyomtatás">Póló nyomtatás</a> </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://fotografika.hu/kategoria/17/ajandektargy-nyomtatas/baba-ruha-nyomtatas" title="Baba ruha nyomtatás">Baba ruha nyomtatás</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                
                </li>
```